# Get non normalized eigenvectors in scipy

Tags: scipy, eigenvector

Scipy and Numpy returns eigenvectors normalized.  I am trying to use the vectors for a physical application and I need them to not be normalized.

For example 
`a = np.matrix('-3, 2; -1, 0')
W,V = spl.eig(a)`

scipy returns eigenvalues (W) of `[-2,-1]` and the modal matrix (V) (eigenvalues as columns) `[[ 0.89442719  0.70710678][ 0.4472136   0.70710678]]`

I need the original modal matrix `[[2 1][1 1]]`

Comment: Can you tell us how you calculate the `original modal matrix`?

Comment: `A*v = l*v` for this example.  I have a more complex example that might have more meaning in this case.  `D1 := l1 × identity(3) − A`, `adj(D1) D1 D1
− 1`, and the contribution to the modal matrix is the last column

Comment: ① The concept of an "original modal matrix" is, ehm, original. ② If in your field, or your application,  it's customary to normalize the eigenvector matrix is a specific way, you are free to multiply each column by a different number, as the eigenvectors are known except for a scaling factor. ③ From a comment below, you seem interested in a threshold on _**eigenvalues**_, but eigenvalues depends only on the system's properties, and not on the normalization you apply to the eigenvectors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to various related threads [(1)](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-December/059648.html) [(2)](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-June/034843.html) [(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77520/what-if-do-not-want-mathematica-to-normalize-eigenvectors-with-eigenvectorsnma), there is no such thing as a "non normalized" eigenvector.

Indeed, an eigenvector `v` corresponding to the eigenvalue `l` of the matrix `A` is defined by,

```
A*v = l*v
```

and can therefore be multiplied by any scalar and remain valid.

While depending on the algorithm, the computed eigenvector can have a norm different from 1,  this does not hold any particular meaning (physical or otherwise), and should not be relied on. It is customary to return a normalized eigenvector in most numerical libraries (scipy, R, matlab, etc).

Comment: I am trying to replicate a function where someone does seem to think that the norm has meaning.  I have seen one other reference to using this type of analysis (someone else looking for the same answer).  I power systems we are using this to determine stability.  Based on the value of the norm, we ignore the smaller eigenvalues.

Comment: @blindguy It's not so much a programming issue, as a mathematical problem (since mathematically it does not make sens). Could you provide a link to the method you are using that relies on it? There must be some information missing regarding how the eigenvectors should be normalized...

Comment: I think I am missing information, hence trying to find help on forums.  The math forum has not helped.  I am probably describing wrong in terms of the math.  The documentation for the software I am replicating calls it `modal analysis`.  At least one paper refers to the resulting vectors and a modal matrix, and does not represent them in normalized form.  see example starting on page 11 http://engrwww.usask.ca/classes/EE/840/notes/Eigenvalues%20and%20Eigenvectors.pdf

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at sympy. This package tries to solve this stuff by means of algebraic calculations instead of numeric ones (as numpy does).

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing(use_unicode=True)

mat_a = sp.Matrix([[-3, 2], [-1, 0]])
mat_a.eigenvects()
```

Result is (eigenvalue, multiplicity, eigenvector):

```
[(-2, 1, [[2],[1]]), (-1, 1, [[1],[1]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that normalizing eigenvectors can also **change the direction/sign** of the vectors. This could have consequences for some applications and the programmer should double check to ensure the signs make sense.