# How to return unnormalized eigenvectors in `numpy.linalg.eig`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to get the eigenvectors of a matrix, but I do not want them to be normalized.

By default [numpy.linalg.eig](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) returns normalized eigenvectors.  But, rather than multiplying this result by the norm (which will introduce an unnecessary additional numerical errors), I want it to just return the eigenvectors not normalized, but as they are originally.

Is there a smooth way to do this in either `numpy` or `scipy`?  I am more familiar with numpy, so a solution there is best, but scipy would also be acceptable.

Comment: Some discussion in [this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946407/get-non-normalized-eigenvectors-in-scipy)

Comment: yeah good point, I actually vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get non normalized eigenvectors in scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946407/get-non-normalized-eigenvectors-in-scipy)